# No wifi with N1525 or external netgear A6210

Tags: wireless, broadcom, netgear

Wifi is not working on Xubuntu 15.10. I have tried two different cards (build in (Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac) and external usb card (Netgear A6210). The official troubleshooting guide does not work step one (nm-tools: command not found). I have installed drivers according to corresponding instructions, but that didn't help any.

Please see the output of iwconfig,  uname -a, route -n, lspci -nnk: 
 http://pastebin.com/aDcYCanu

The output of lspci -nn, dmsg, rfkill list all: http://pastebin.com/z6w27ECM

I tried to follow advice in *kind of similar* threads. I've spent two weeks, several times recovered OS from Clonezilla image. So, please don't mark this is a duplicate.

Thank you in advance,
Stepan

Comment: Please give us another pastebin: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: [    3.456340] ath3k: probe of 1-9:1.0 failed with error -2
[    3.456362] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[    3.467630] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver netathr7x; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
[  130.461474] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$

Comment: Above is with # blacklist bcm43xx. I will post the output when bcm43xx is blacklisted.

Comment: after returning to blacklisting the bcm43xx the output is  stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$ sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath
[sudo] password for stepan: 
[    3.488299] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver netathr7x; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
[    3.501204] ath3k: probe of 1-9:1.0 failed with error -2
[    3.501226] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   67.011228] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0

Comment: bcm43xx has nothing to do with either of your devices. Is ndiswrapper an attempt to get the N1525 internal wireless working? Is the usual native linux driver ath10k_pci blacklisted? I was expecting to see that it is missing firmware so that we could download and install it. Any clues here? `dmesg | grep firm`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UJT0z3LM

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VavGLMhK

Comment: I am  new to Linux. I've used fully configured systems for years, but I am for the first time committed to make it work myself. So, I will gladly post output, but I can't "check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver' ", because I don't know what it means. Thank you for your help.

Comment: ndiswrapper shows currently installed drivers: netathr7x; hardware present: yes.   Should I also see other drivers, given that I have two wireless cards?

Comment: Please refer to my answer. If we get the Killer going, we needn't bother with the impossible USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `ndiswrapper` will be ineffective as I suspect there are no Windows XP driver files available for your device. Let's erase the installation:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -e netathr7x
sudo rm /etc/ndiswrapper/*
```

Next, the driver `ath10k_pci` doesn't appear to load automatically. Please check to see if it is blacklisted:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

If it is listed as blacklisted, remove the listing, proofread, save and close the text editor.

Next, we see that you lack the needed firmware:

> ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin failed with error -2

I suggest that you do:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
```

Reboot. Let us see another paste of `dmesg | grep ath10`.

Comment: stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$ sudo ndiswrapper -e netathr7x
[sudo] password for stepan: 
stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$ sudo rm /etc/ndiswrapper/*
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/ndiswrapper/*’: No such file or directory
stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$ 
Working on it. I will post an update once I go through these steps.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gEJTAr2K not blacklisted afaik

Comment: Also check: `ls  /etc/modprobe.d`  Thanks.

Comment: I have /lib/firmware/ with ath6k, ath9k_htc, ath10k. ath10k has QCA988X

Comment: Which chown and security should I set for those? Root - read/write; root group - read; others -none?

Comment: They are probably correct as is. We will uncover any problems after reboot and `dmesg | grep ath10k`.

Comment: stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$ sudo dmesg | grep ath10k
[sudo] password for stepan: 
stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$

Comment: Nothing found (blank )

Comment: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath10` <--This reinforces my belief that the driver is blacklisted.

Comment: btw, after reboot everything is ok, but Thunar (file manager) lags for a minute (literally). Once it opens it works normally.

Comment: stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$ sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath10
[sudo] password for stepan: 
[  420.831760] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$

Comment: Can you please paste your entire `dmesg`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qL1rFtSA thank you for helping

Comment: Looks like it's working!! Please check: `iwconfig`. Also, what does this tell us? `rfkill list all`

Comment: stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$ iwconfig
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$

Comment: stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$ rfkill list all
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$

Comment: You have a wireless interface `wlp3s0` and it is not blocked by the hardware switch. When you click the Network Manager icon, does it see networks? Does it scan? `sudo iwlist scan` We needn't see the entire list; just yes or no.

Comment: hmm, it moved from"can't see networks" to "cannot connect". this is just one step away from sucess now. Can you please explain the voodoo magic behind? Was it just dl the board.bin and firmware-5.bin and reboot?

Comment: meanwhile i will create unprotected guest network and try to connect

Comment: Pretty much! We still have some housekeeping to do.

Comment: Also, can you please comment on my dmesg. Do you see anything suspicious there? I have reasons to believe that this os is compromised (gksudo and parted get uninstalled randomly and some other stuff happens)

Comment: Hmm. I logged on to router (using wired connection), checked the wireless password and tried to connect by wifi. All networks dissapeared... I will reboot.

Comment: With the USB wireless detached,  please!

Comment: I rebooted with USB and wired cable *unplugged*. I am exactly in the same spot I was when I started the post... I still have the/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/ with board.bin and firmware-5.bin

Comment: stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$ sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath10
[sudo] password for stepan: 
[  444.117479] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
stepan@stepan-LX:~/Desktop$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31882/discussion-on-answer-by-chili555-no-wifi-with-n1525-or-external-netgear-a6210).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cA0zv0BG apparently wlan is both soft and hard blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I can finaly reliably enable/disable wireless with just fn+F2 key. I can even connect to iphone hotspot and unencrypted wireless networks. I can't connect to encrypted network of my home router, but this is a different story (I will post it on AskUbuntu).
It is puzzling that I don't know what exactly helped. It seems like disabling ndiswrapper + downloading board.bin and firmware-5.bin did the trick. It would be nice to hear chili555's view on this.
Thank you for your help, Chili555.
Cheers, 
Stepan