# Changing the desktop to Mate

Tags: wireless, broadcom, mate

Background:
I've installed xfce on my laptop and all worked great except for wi-fi. I've spent a week or so fixing it, then posted a question on Askubuntu. Chili555 helped me, but I afraid that help isn't really reproducible
[No wifi with N1525 or external netgear A6210](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700454/no-wifi-with-n1525-or-external-netgear-a6210)
Then I backed up my system and moved to Ubuntu Mate. Everything worked out of box, except for wi-fi. Copy-pasting `/lib/firmware/ath10k` fixed the problem, so I didn't even bother to make a backup (silly me). One of the upgrades bricked the system. I reinstalled OS, copy-pasted `/lib/firmware/ath10k`, but my wireless remained dead. https://askubuntu.com/questions/753545/ubuntu-wi-fi-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-16-04

I would like to have a Mate desktop with wi-fi working. What is the best way to proceed? Should I try to replace xfce with Mate using some `sudo` command (if so - which command?), or again ask Chili555 for some help (is pm OK?), or should I open a new thread about my wi-fi (why would a new thread better than the old one)?

edited: added typical messages for `dmesg | grep ath`

```
[  616.134730] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -108    
[  616.547924] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to delete WMI vdev 0: -108     
[  616.547933] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: removing stale peer d6:04:cd:86:2a:53 from vdev_id 0     
[  616.572206] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to delete WMI vdev 1: -108    
[  616.572221] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not suspend target (-108)     
[  627.999225] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
```

Also, is this command relevant?

```
options ath10k_core skip_otp=Y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
```

Comment: "...or again ask Chili555 for some help..." Certainly! I'm happy to help. Please edit your question to add the result of: `dmesg | grep ath`.

Comment: Chili555, here is the output. http://pastebin.com/yqpn0YEr. (1) Networks started to work suddenly. Thanks to your strong aura, probable. Can you please briefly comment on messages in attached dmesg output, so I can mark your answer as solution. Besides, it will help others when fixing their wifi. Thanks.

Comment: Story changed:  http://pastebin.com/u1k5pu7c Now I have my wifi grayed out. ..

Comment: The latest paste looks very good, actually. Is there a wireless interface `wlp3s0` in the output of: `iwconfig`? Is there some other clue here? `dmesg | grep -e wlp -e etwork`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Yk34SX67     and   http://pastebin.com/Gk6n4C14  Thank you

Comment: most recent:    http://pastebin.com/NUrnUPBQ

This command, suggested elsewhere does something, but I am not sure what exactly

   echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=Y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf

Comment: I assume th alarming messages signal that the supplied firmware is incorrect. Which do you have? `ls -al /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1` Where did you get the firmware? wget as from the other thread?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing wifi on a clean install of Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

## Killer 1525 specific firmware:

Download:
https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
and put it in the /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/ folder (create the folder if it doesn’t exist)
Follow steps described here:
http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux/20-killer-wireless-ac-in-linux-ubuntu-debian

Briefly:

Download:
https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
Note: At the time of editing this article, it is posted as:
https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1
and put it in the /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/ folder as firmware-4.bin.